# How do I access files in my S3 bucket for my rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-s3, carrierwave, fog

I have successfully setup Fog, Carrierwave & Heroku to work with my S3 bucket for file and image uploads.

What I want to be able to do is to allow some users the ability to see some of the images uploaded to the server. Almost like a "file browser" if you will.

How do I do this and how do I do it securely?

I am using AWS's IAM user policies and created an S3 user account just for S3 access.